# Función para determinar el tipo de objeto en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Esta pregunta surgió de una respuesta a otra pregunta en la cual se quería determinar si una variable Javascript era del tipo `String`.

Como sabemos, existen varios métodos para determinar los tipos de variables, pero dichos métodos no son uniformes.

Por ejemplo, si tengo dos variables:

```
var strUno="Cadena uno";
var strDos=new String("Cadena dos");
```

Si uso `typeof` para determinar el tipo, no funcionará igual para las dos variables.

¿Cómo determinar entonces el tipo de objeto, si es `string`, `number`, `boolean`, etc, tanto para objetos como para primitivos?

> Nota: Esta pregunta conlleva una auto-respuesta que será marcada como
>   Wiki de comunidad.

Answer (score 4):

Para determinar el tipo de una variable primitiva se suele usar [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/typeof), el cual:

> devuelve una cadena que indica el tipo del operando sin evaluarlo.
>   operando es la cadena, variable, palabra clave u objeto para el que se
>   devolverá su tipo.

El problema es que, si se trata de un objeto del tipo `String`, si usamos `typeof` éste nos dirá que se trata de un objeto, pero es incapaz de determinar de qué tipo es ese objeto.

Eso lo podemos ver ejecutando el siguiente código:

```
var strUno="Cadena 1";
var objUno=new String("Cadena 1");
print (typeof strUno); 
print (typeof objUno);
```

**Resultado:**

```
string
object
```

La siguiente función usa [`Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/toString) para determinar los siguientes tipos:

- string
- number
- boolean
- array
- null
- object
- undefined

<kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/OKX14655)**</kbd>

```
   /**
     * Obtiene el tipo de un objeto dado.
     *
     * @param {object} objParam: objeto pasado en parámetro.
     * @return {string} strResultado: cadena descriptiva del tipo de objeto.
     */

    function getType(objParam) {
        var strResultado = "";
        strTipo = Object.prototype.toString.call(objParam);
        print(strTipo);

      switch (strTipo) {
        case "[object String]":
          strResultado = "string";
          break;

        case "[object Number]":
          strResultado = "number";
          break;

        case "[object Boolean]":
          strResultado = "boolean";
          break;

        case "[object Array]":
          strResultado = "array";
          break; 

        case "[object Null]":
          strResultado = "null";
          break; 

        case "[object Object]":
          strResultado = "object";
          break;

        case "[object Undefined]":
          strResultado = "undefined";
          break;

        default:
          strResultado = "error";
          break;
      }

      return strResultado;
    }


    /*Prueba de código*/

    var strTipoObjeto="objeto";
    var strTipoPrimitivo="primitivo";


    print("CADENAS:\n");
        var strObject=new String("Objeto del tipo String");
        print('El '+strTipoObjeto+' "'+strObject+ '" es del tipo: '+getType(strObject)+'\n');

        var strPrimitivo="Cadena primitiva";
        print('El '+strTipoPrimitivo+' "'+strPrimitivo+ '" es del tipo: '+getType(strPrimitivo)+'\n');

    print("ENTEROS:\n");
        var intObject=new Number(22);
        print('El '+strTipoObjeto+' '+intObject+ ' es del tipo: '+getType(intObject)+'\n');

        var intPrimitivo=-22;
        print('El '+strTipoPrimitivo+' '+intPrimitivo+ ' es del tipo: '+getType(intPrimitivo)+'\n');

    print("BOOLEANOS:\n");
        var bolObject=new Boolean(true);
        print('El '+strTipoObjeto+' '+bolObject+ ' es del tipo: '+getType(bolObject)+'\n');

        var bolPrimitivo=false;
        print('El '+strTipoPrimitivo+' '+bolPrimitivo+ ' es del tipo: '+getType(bolPrimitivo)+'\n');

    print("ARRAYS:\n");
        var arrObject=new Array("test");
        print('El '+strTipoObjeto+' "'+arrObject+ '" es del tipo: '+getType(arrObject)+'\n');

        var arrPrimitivo=["test"];
        print('El '+strTipoPrimitivo+' "'+arrPrimitivo+ '" es del tipo: '+getType(arrPrimitivo)+'\n');


    print("NULL:\n");
        var nullObject=new Object();
        nullObject=null;
        print('El '+strTipoObjeto+' "'+nullObject+ '" es del tipo: '+getType(nullObject)+'\n');

        var nullPrimitivo=null;
        print('El '+strTipoPrimitivo+' "'+nullPrimitivo+ '" es del tipo: '+getType(nullPrimitivo)+'\n');


    print("OBJETOS:\n");
        var objCar = new Object();
            objCar.make = 'Ford';
            objCar.model = 'Mustang';
            objCar.year = 1969;
        print('El '+strTipoObjeto+' "'+objCar+ '" es del tipo: '+getType(objCar)+'\n');


    print("UNDEFINED:\n");
        var undefinedPrimitivo=undefined;
        print('El '+strTipoPrimitivo+' "'+undefinedPrimitivo+ '" es del tipo: '+getType(undefinedPrimitivo)+'\n');
```

---

**Resultado de la prueba:**

```
CADENAS:

El objeto "Objeto del tipo String" es del tipo: string
El primitivo "Cadena primitiva" es del tipo: string

ENTEROS:

El objeto 22 es del tipo: number
El primitivo -22 es del tipo: number

BOOLEANOS:

El objeto true es del tipo: boolean
El primitivo false es del tipo: boolean

ARRAYS:

El objeto "test" es del tipo: array
El primitivo "test" es del tipo: array

NULL:

El objeto "null" es del tipo: null
El primitivo "null" es del tipo: null

OBJETOS:

El objeto "[object Object]" es del tipo: object

UNDEFINED:

El primitivo "undefined" es del tipo: undefined
```

---

### OTRA POSIBILIDAD

En [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/332429/5587982) de SO en inglés se indica que con una función como esta:

```
Object.prototype.getName = function() { 
   var funcNameRegex = /function (.{1,})\(/;
   var results = (funcNameRegex).exec((this).constructor.toString());
   return (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : "";
};
```

Podríamos obtener el tipo solamente haciendo esto:

```
print("Test".getName());
```

**Resultado:**

```
String
```

El problema es que no funciona con `null` o con `undefined`.

Comment: Creo que habría que añadir información sobre la palabra reservada `typeof`y sus limitaciones, explicando por qué no se está usando en esta solución